# adding element to list multiple times prolog

Tags: list, prolog, append

So here is the problem: Write a predicate

`triple(Xs,Ys)` <- Each element in `Ys` is member of `Xs` and occurs three successive  times in  `Ys`

Example:

```
?- triple([a,b,c], L).
L = [a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c] 


add(X,Xs,[X|Xs]).
```

`triple(Xs,Ys):- add(X,Xs,[X|Ys])`

This appends the items to the list such as
`?- triple([1,2,3],L).`
`L = [3, 4, 5] .`

How do I make it append multiple times I have tried re-entering the line but to no avail or putting in commas and re-entering again, I even tried a list concatenation but it only added the same list infinite times.

Answer (score 1):

A simple mode could be the following

```
triple([], []).
triple([H | Ti], [H, H, H | To]) :-
  triple(Ti, To).
```